# Conversão de Types com Fluenti API no EF Core 2.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, code-first, entity-framework-core

Gostaria de saber se é possível fazer a seguinte conversão:

```
public class Pessoa 
{
    public bool Ativo { get; set; }
}

public class PessoaMap: IEntityTypeConfiguration<Pessoa>
{
    public virtual void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<TEntity> builder)
    {
         builder.Property(x => x.Ativo)
            .HasConversion(?) 
         // Converter o meu campo bool em char no banco de dados, por exemplo, quando for true inserir no banco de dados "S", ou inverso "N"
    }
}

    Tabela Pessoa

    | Ativo |
|1| |  'S'  |
|2| |  'N'  |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você precisa criar a conversão via lambda, a primeira, é o parse do `bool` para `char`, a segunda, de `char` para `bool` (usada ao carregar do banco de dados)

```
public class PessoaMap: IEntityTypeConfiguration<Pessoa>
{
    public virtual void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<TEntity> builder)
    {
         builder.Property(x => x.Ativo)
            .HasConversion(
                x => x.Ativo ? "S" : "N",
                x => x.Equals("S"));
    }
}
```

Existem vários conversores pré-definidos que podem ser utilizados, inclusive alguns para seu caso, o exemplo acima é uma demonstração de um conversor criado na mão, e pode servir de exemplo para outras conversões.

Os conversores já existentes podem ser encontrados no link de referência da resposta.

Fonte: [Value Conversions - Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/ef/core/modeling/value-conversions)

Comment: Obrigado, era isso mesmo que precisava, só teve um porém, eu não consigo fazer um isso usando a classe ValueConverter<bool, char> () e colocar a expressão aqui dentro, por alguma motivo ele só aceita campo string ao invés de char, então nesse caso tive que fazer a conversão dentro do HasConversion mesmo.

Comment: Legal cara! Realmente não testei a solução pq escrevi pelo celular, mas já atualizei.